# Using scanf() to read "00"

Tags: c, scanf

I'm very new to programming and am trying to make a basic American roulette game using only numbers, one number that appears on the board is "00", I am trying to assign "00" to a variable in a structure array and I am not sure how to do this specific number as it reads it as "0". Here is the code I am using to set it up, sorry for the probably very stupid question but I have been searching for a few hours and only extremely complex answers have come up that I couldn't possibly understand yet (although I've tried). The input needs to be read in one due to the very basic compiler I'm using on request such that an input will be "number number number number number number number number".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    struct bet /* Setting up a structure array to store input values */
    {
        float number;
        float betValue;
    } playerBet[4];

    scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", &playerBet[0].number, &playerBet[0].betValue, &playerBet[1].number, &playerBet[1].betValue,&playerBet[2].number, &playerBet[2].betValue,&playerBet[3].number, &playerBet[3].betValue);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you take the inputs as strings, you can check for the `"00"` and then call it, say, `37`. Otherwise `sscanf` the strings to extract the number. But I advise against using `float` for what is an integer value. I would also advise against using `float` for the money: better to work in cents. If you must use floating pont, never use `float` where you can use `double`.

Comment: I didn't know that. So it must be read as a string then.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you very much, I can now get it to read "00". I haven't been introduced to sscanf yet, can I use that to compare numbers then? I will be using a switch statement to check if i have a winning value so for the case statements to pull the number from the playerBet[0].number i would use sscanf?

Comment: You use `sscanf` in a similar way to `scanf`, after getting input with `fgets`. See the man page. One big advantage is that unlike `scanf` the function does not "block" when the input requirements are not satisfied. Always check the return value from these functions, which tells you *how many items were converted*. I suggested you treat `"00"` as `37` because you then have 38 numbers in the range `0...37` and you can make a special case of `0` and `37` (actually `"00"`). Also, "red/black" and "odd/even" etc can be extracted from the value, reducing the number of case statements.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've now implemented the fgets and sscanf, thank you very much for the point in the right direction, it makes a lot more sense than using scanf. I'm slightly confused on what you mean by treat 00 as 37, how would I go about that? Sorry for the amount of questions, I'm learning as I go.

Comment: `int wheelnum; if(instr[0] == '0' && instr[1] == '0') wheelnum = 37; else  sscanf(instr, "%d", &wheelnum);` although this example needs formatting and should be doing some error checking. Then for example `int even = (wheelnum % 2 == 0);` and so on, with exceptions for the special cases `0` and `37` (which internally, you know represents `"00"`).

Comment: for a problem like this you want to be as familiar as possible with all the functions provided by the three big libraries:  `stdio.h, string.h, and stdlib.h`.  And also **all** the conversion formats available for `scanf, sscanf, printf, and fprintf` such as `%d`  `%i`  `%f` and `%s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For floating point numbers and integers, `0` and `00` are not distinguishable. As @Weather Vane pointed out in the comments, you can use a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to distinguish double-zero. You can also input each data point as a string (as `"0" and "00"` are distinguished as different when interpreted as character arrays).

For these kinds of small projects that are simple (and likely homework problems), you can use [`atoi()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=atoi&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) to convert strings to numeric values to parse your input.

You should probably be using integers to model your data internally. This will ensure you don't run into problems when checking evenness or oddness of your input. Your data structure doesn't seem to require modeling floating-point data.

## Example

Make your structure element `number` an integer, and the `betValue` a `float`:

```
int number;
float betValue;
```

Input number as string and parse it:

```
char input_number[3]; // 2 spaces plus null terminator
int number;           // numeric version (after parsing)
float bet_value;      // float value for bet
scanf("%s %f", input_number, &bet_value);
if (input_number[0] == '0' && input_number[1] == '0') {
    number = 37;
} else {
    number = atoi(input_number);
}
// Assign them to structure
playerBet[0].number = number;
playerBet[0].betValue = bet_value;
```

Comment: The advantage of using integer numbers is that (except for `0` and `00` which do not apply) the zones of the board are easily computable.  Red/black, high/low, etc. and betting perms like "street" and "corner" too.

Comment: I agree, however for the input you wouldn't want the user to have to enter `"37"`, so you would probably input a character array and then parse it.

Comment: You would not want the user to enter `-1` or `100` either. Of course there must be some error- and range-checking.

Comment: Of course, but that is off-topic. I am saying that the use of a sentinel value of `37` is good, but not for user input. The OP should be inputting this data as character arrays so that the user can enter `00` and have the software interpret this as `37` (or however the OP wants to model the data internally).

Comment: And yes I agree, integers should also be used to model the internal data (not floats). I only referenced those since the OP did in the question.

Comment: So for the sentinel value i'm slightly confused as to how I can achieve this, i saw the code written by weather vane but still am a bit confused on it, i understand the principle behind it and that actually solves a problem i would have had later.      if(playerBet[0].number[0] == '0' && playerBet[0].number[1] == '0') playerBet[0].number[0] = 37; Should this code not work? It gives me the result of "%0".

Comment: if `playerBet[0].number` is of type `float`, then it will probably not equal `'0'`, since `'0' == 48`, since `'0'` is a `char`. You should input character arrays, not floats.

Comment: @GregSchmit Thank you very much for the extremely detailed answer, I really appreciate that, I can now see how it all works, I tried implementing it however it comes back with a fatal runtime error, I've checked all the syntax to make sure it is correct multiple times and could not find a problem.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main( void )
{
char input_number[3]; // 2 spaces plus null terminator
int Number;           // numeric version (after parsing)
float bet_value;      // float value for bet

struct bet /* Setting up a structure array to store input values */
{
float number;
float betValue;
} playerBet[4];


scanf("%s %f", input_number, bet_value);

if (input_number[0] == '0' && input_number[1] == '0') {
    Number = 37;
} else {
    Number = atoi(input_number);
}
...... I then did the assigning. This now works but i can't use words.

Comment: You should take an intro to C programming course like this one: https://learncodethehardway.org/c/.

Comment: I did have an error though: in the `scanf` statement I should've passed the address of bet_value (as in, `scanf("%s %f", input_number, &bet_value);`). It is fixed now if you want to try that. Otherwise, you should give compiler errors, don't just tell me there was a "fatal error".

Comment: I no longer have any errors, thank you very much! The only problem I have now is using words but i will come to that in the future. I wish I could have given you a better compiler error but unfortunately that is all it gives me, I have been tasked to do this on the absolute most basic compiler. Is there a way you know of like strcpy to copy the data of a string into a struct array variable? Thank you very much for your help too!!

Comment: @ConradYeadon `strcpy()` can copy a string for you. For more info, see the man page here: freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?strcpy(3). `memcpy()` could also work. If you found my answer helpful, feel free to upvote it as well.